# How to render component dynamically from server using API call?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-components, angular-dynamic-components

I have a dynamic component, which is working with param (:pagename) its a dynamic page, I have some custom pages those are stored in Admin portal like I have customReport page on admin when I hit the URL with customReport, I call the Rest API on dynamic component and get response from API that contains like

result:[{html:Example,component:'component code here'}];

I want to bind that Html on dynamiccomponent.html and inject customReport.ts to use functions of this component.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this content? [Angular Html Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

```
<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>
```

Comment: i know, but how to render component from API response.